# PublisherAdView loadAd performance issue on Android

Tags: android, performance, google-dfp

I had some performance issues with an application (UI rendering would freeze for moments), did some digging and found that PublisherAdView.loadAd() method takes about 500-700ms to execute on Nexus 5 on cold app start and 100-200ms on subsequent runs. I expected 10-15ms at worst.

To verify this, I downloaded Banner Example from here: https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/dfp/android/banner and modified MainActivity to execute loadAd() method in a seperate method:

```
private PublisherAdView mAdView;
private PublisherAdRequest adRequest;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);

    mAdView = (PublisherAdView) findViewById(R.id.ad_view);

    adRequest = new PublisherAdRequest.Builder().build();

    loadAd();
}

 private void loadAd(){

    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

    // Start loading the ad in the background.
    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);

    long end = System.currentTimeMillis();

    Log.d("MyActivity", "loadAd took "+(end - start)+" ms");
}
```

The problem becomes even more obvious when there are more ads to show at the same time (banner at the beginning of an article, rectangle ad below introduction...) and UI freezes for half a second or even more until they are loaded.

This is also issue when showing ads in RecyclerView and UI freezes during scrolling until ad is loaded.

Am I missing something here or this is indeed PublisherAdView issue?

Answer (score 2):

I have a similar experience, adMob uses webviews, under the hood, which is dreadfully inefficient on Android devices and taxing the CPU. The initial long load times are Android connecting to the Chromium plugin to start a webview session. Once in memory it will improve. It's most noticeable when used in lists/recycler views.

The approach I use, is to display banners once in fragments and activities. Refresh is configurable on the ad server side. I would avoid inserting ads into lists, (such as inserting an ad into every nth element), but if you must, record a flag using view.setTag to indicate the ad has been loaded.

This flag can actually be the time the ad was loaded. Then use that tag in your bindViewHolder of your recyclerview, or getItem in a conventional listView to determine if the ad has been loaded. If the ad has already been loaded, then just display current contents/layout, otherwise if it has expired (by some arbitrary amount of time like 30 seconds), or the value is not set, then send a loadAd request), but then you take a performance hit again.

So, when the user scrolls around, the scrolling performance gradually improves as you don't keep requesting ads every time the list element gets instantiated. Also when using Fragments make sure you PublisherAdView.pause() your ad if the fragment espcially, if it's in a viewpager during onDestroyView.